# Question About Shifter Functionality?

Tags: shimano, shifting, derailleur-front, tourney

I’m a new bike rider and I’m trying to get a lot more into biking and understanding bikes and what not.

However, I recently bought a Cannondale Quick CX 4 (about a month ago) and I’m having issues with the front gear shifter.

It’s a Shimano 7-speed Tourney microshifter (what it said on the website, I could be wrong). It has no problems shifting to the smallest gear, but when I shift up to a larger gear the lever doesn’t move the little red line (see picture) enough to reach the larger gear. As a result, the chain, instead of switching gears, starts grinding on the derailleur. This only really happens when shifting from shifting from gear 2 to 3 (if I start from gear 1 and quickly pump it up to gear 3 I can usually get the chain to move to the biggest gear, but not when I’ve been comfortably riding at gear 2 and then want to gain speed).

Could anyone explain to me why this might be happening/how to fix it? Is it a me issue? I watched a Park Tools video on how to adjust your front derailleurs but I don’t think that’s the problem.

[image: front gears bike shifter]

Answer (score 4):

Background: Derailleurs are essentially springs and shifters are ratchet mechanisms that pull on cables to counteract the springs.
Ideally, all of the steps below are performed in a stand where you can spin the pedals forward freely.

First thing I could check is if the limit screws are preventing the derailleur from moving.
To check this, try to move the derailleur by hand.
This can be require quite a bit of force on the front derailleur.
If its too difficult and you have exposed cable along your down tube or top tube, you can pull on that directly.

If pulling on the cable makes it seem like there's a hard stop preventing the derailleur from moving enough, you need to adjust the high limit screw.
If you can move the derailleur beyond when the shifter puts it, you likely need to add tension to the cable so that it can use more force to counteract the derailleur's spring.

It could also be both of these things.
It could also be that rhe alignment of the derailleur is an issue as well.
The outer cage should be parallel to the chainrings.

Park Tool's YouTube will explain how to adjust all of these things better than I could.

Comment: For completeness. https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment